# Why do I get a seg fault when trying to access a character in a string

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, queue

I'm trying to store commands in a queue and read them from the queue later on. I'm using [this queue](https://github.com/SMFSW/Queue) because the code needs to run on an Arduino. When accessing the first (or any) character, I'm getting a segmentation fault. What am I doing wrong here?

```
int main() {
    cppQueue q(sizeof(char*), 10);
    char c1[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};

    q.push(&c1);

    char *command;
    q.pop(&command);
    char first = command[0];  <-- error
    // do stuff with first

    return 0;
};
```

Thanks for any help!

PS: This works:

```
cppQueue q(sizeof(int), 10);
int x = 1;
q.push(&x);
int numba;
q.pop(&numba);
std::cout << numba << "\n"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are not pointers. Arrays can automatically converted to pointers in most case of expressions, but one of the exception is used with unary `&` operator.

With `q.push(&c1);`, the queue will read the contents of the array (plus some garbage for out-of-range region) instaed of a valid pointer value.

Use a pointer variable to feed the queue a pointer.

```
int main() {
    cppQueue q(sizeof(char*), 10);
    char c1[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
    char* p = c1;

    q.push(&p);

    char *command;
    q.pop(&command);
    char first = command[0];
    // do stuff with first

    return 0;
}
```